# How do I print directly from php7

Tags: php, windows, apache, dll, xampp

I want to know if there is printer dll for php 7 or if there is some other option to print directly from php.
I tried to use and old printer.dll in php7 however I get the following error :

```
Call to undefined function printer_open()
```

Comment: This is part of the [PECL printer](https://pecl.php.net/package/printer) package, which appears to be dead.

Comment: So I can't use printers in PHP? or there is other way?

Comment: _"there is other way?"_ Use a unix-based OS. :)

Comment: But how will I print through PHP in unix-based OS?